# How do I return a first class module from the same module?

Tags: ocaml

This code gives "Unbound module type Test":

```
module type Test = sig
  val test : int -> (module Test)
end
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: IIRC, only functors can return modules.

Comment: @Bergi There are first class modules in OCaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the same module as the one being constructed clearly requires recursion. However, recursive module types are not directly allowed only recursive modules. The solution is thus to wrap the module type inside a recursive module:

```
module rec Test: sig
  module type t = sig val test: int -> (module Test.t) end
end = Test
```

Note that the code above is using a classical trick to avoid writing twice a module type without any runtime components.
Then, the new module type can be used with:

```
module rec X: Test.t = struct let test x = (module X:Test.t) end;;
module T = (val X.test 1)
module T2 = (val T.test 2)
```

Comment: So `(val X.test 1)` just returns another copy of `X`? Either way, I think this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: `X.test 1` returns a packed module that is a copy of `X` and `(val ...)` unpacks the packed module into a standard module.